# При сортировке пузырьковым методом появляется ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, массивы, исключения

```
public class NmbSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int[] nmbArr = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < nmbArr.length; i++) {
            nmbArr[i] = Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine());
        }

        System.out.println("До сортировки: " + Arrays.toString(nmbArr));

        int temp;
        for (int x = nmbArr.length - 1; x > 0; x--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nmbArr.length; i++) {
                if (nmbArr[i] > nmbArr[i + 1]) {
                    temp = nmbArr[i];
                    nmbArr[i] = nmbArr[i + 1];
                    nmbArr[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("После сортировки: " + Arrays.toString(nmbArr));
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>
> До сортировки: [5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
>
> at level6.task140_lev6_lec11.NmbSort.main(NmbSort.java:20)*

Comment: `at level6.task140_lev6_lec11.NmbSort.main(NmbSort.java:20)` - тут явно указана строчка, в оторой ошибка произошла, было бы неплохо, если бы вы на нее посмотрели.и попробовали сами разобраться, если не сможете, то хотя бы выделите эту строку в вашем куске кода

Comment: Извините, сразу добавил, а потом случайно удалил.
Строка *if (nmbArr[i] > nmbArr[i + 1]) {*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в цикле по `i`.
i может принимать значение `nmbArr.length-1`, затем, в `if`, идет обращение к `nmbArr[nmbArr.length]`, тут и выскакивает `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

P.S. Ошибка `*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5` говорит, что было обращение к `5`-ому элементу массива, из-за чего и образовалась ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Разгадка, как всегда, скрывалась в очевидном)

P. S. А на всех сайтах, на которых читал, метод работал именно в таком виде...

Comment: @StanleyKubrik, Странно, что такое работает... Возможно, там массив был задан на, минимум, один элемент больше. Алгоритм отрабатывал хорошо и не выдавал ошибки. Тут же ровно 5 элементов [0..4] и обращается к 5-ому. Вообще, вряд ли оно так написано на многих сайтах